# Alternatives to eval() of a string

Tags: python

I have a have dict of dataframes named `tr`. Each dataframe is named like `train_fold_1`.  To call a dataframe looks like this: `tr['train_fold_1']`.

I would like to select a section of each of these dataframes and rename them.

This works:

```
i = 2
X_ = {}
X_[i] = eval("tr['df_train_fold_" + str(i) + "']").iloc[:,1]
```

But how can I do this process without using `eval()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `eval()` here at all, as the names for the dataframes are not *variable names* but just *strings* used as keys in a dictionary.

```
i = 2
X_ = {}
X_[i] = tr['df_train_fold_' + str(i)].iloc[:,1]
```

Comment: Or `X_ = {fold.split('_')[-1]: df.iloc[:,1] for fold, df in tr.items()}` to always be making a key-->val dict with different operations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get your keys as integer instead of strings (can be useful in some cases) you can replace "eval" with "int".

Comment: But `int("tr['df_train_fold_" + str(i) + "']")` doesn't work.

Comment: Haha you can't convert to integer literally tr['df_train_fold_" + str(i) + "']" try just int(tr['df_train_fold_" + str(i) + "']) without the " around tr[...]. Seeing this that might by why the eval causing a problem.